# Jquery pop up close buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Hi with help from the stackoverflow contributors I have created a jquery click , popup and close button.

The current issue is my trying to make the red square be the close btn and if you click around off the opened box for that to close too.

Can anybody help?

Here is my Fiddle>http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/301/

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500); 
});

$('#overlay').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500); 
});

$('.callme').on('click', function (e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `#overlay-back` to your second `click` function

```
$('#overlay, #overlay-back').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500); 
});
```

**[Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/303/)**

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add the `overlayback` function:

```
$('#overlay-back').on('click', function () { 
$('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500); });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/302/)

Comment: Felix has a solution much cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500); 
});

$('#overlay').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500); 
});

$('.callme').on('click', function (e) { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500); 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/308/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `fadeToggle()` too

```
$('#some-button, #overlay').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeToggle(500); 
});

$('#overlay-back').on('click', function () { 
    $('.callme, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500); 
});
```

[JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/309/)